# Admob not showing up in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, admob, swift2

I am trying to implement Admobs into my app using the test `adUnitID`. When I attempt to do so and run it in the simulator nothing shows up in the View. I am superimposing the ad on a `GMSMapView`.

```
        private var gAds: GADBannerView = GADBannerView()

        gAds.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        gAds.rootViewController = self
        gAds.delegate = self
        gAds.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
            self.view.frame.size.height -
                gAds.frame.size.height,
            gAds.frame.size.width,
            gAds.frame.size.height)
        let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
        let adview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationBarHeight + 20, width: gAds.frame.width, height: gAds.frame.height))
        adview.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
        gAds.loadRequest(request)
        adview.addSubview(gAds)
        print(navigationBarHeight)
        self.view.insertSubview(adview, aboveSubview: mapView)
```

Comment: Did you use Cocoapods to install `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK`?

Comment: @CharlesTruluck No I downloaded the SDK from the site

Comment: Assuming that you added the files in the correct place, are you `import GoogleMobileAds`?

Comment: I have no problems with iAds doing it in a similar method to this but Admob seems to be giving me problems.

Comment: If you want to manually install Admob you have to set up the API, where using iAds is built in to the iOS SDK. You can look at installing it here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#manually_using_the_sdk_download

Comment: I did follow that. Print of  `GADRequest.sdkVersion()` : Google Mobile Ads SDK version: afma-sdk-i-v7.5.1

Comment: What file is your code in?

Comment: A UIViewController class

Comment: What does your debugger console say?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an invalid adUnitID, as you are using the demo app's key.
To create one, follow [these](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638) steps.

Comment: That wasn't the issue. The issue was the the `adview` that I was using unnecessarily to place the ad where I wanted where I could just use `gAds = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)` and `gAds.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                navigationBarHeight + 20,
                gAds.frame.size.width,
                gAds.frame.size.height)` and put it above the mapView.

Answer (score 0):

Try tinkering with "navigationBarHeight". I have a banner on the bottom of a Tab Bar View and I had to use "UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 99" for it to work.